# SQL Server join XML siblings by name suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a DB column with XML field like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyObjects]
(
    [Id] [bigint] identity,
    [Details] [xml]
)

INSERT MyObjects(Details) 
VALUES('<List>
    <e>
        <Name>Street bike 1</Name>
        <Type>Object1</Type>
    </e>
    <e>
        <Name>Mountain bike 1</Name>
        <Type>Object2</Type>
    </e>
     <e>
        <Value>350</Value>
        <Type>Value1</Type>
    </e>
    <e>
        <Value>300</Value>
        <Type>Value2</Type>
    </e>
</List>')
```

I'd like to select all object with values like this:

```
Street bike 1, 350 |
Mountain bike 1, 300
```

As you can see suffix of *Type* field in xml indicates how to join objects: Object1=Value1 etc.

This is as far as I went:

```
SELECT 
    objects.e.value('(Name/text())[1]','varchar(100)') ObjectName, 
    '0' ObjectValue
FROM 
    MyObjects mo
CROSS APPLY   
    mo.Details.nodes('(List/e[Type[contains(.,"Object")]])') objects(e)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49003f33b09df6155e343760f265d080

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Seems that really you should have a `Type` and a `ID` node, which would have values `Object`/`Value` and `1`/`2` respectively.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible purely in XQuery

```sql
SELECT mo.Details.query('
  for $e in List/e
  let $t := ($e/Type/text())[1]
  where substring($t, 1, 6) = "Object"
  return (
          ($e/Name/text())[1] cast as xs:string?,
          ",",
          (List/e[Type[text() = concat("Value", substring($t, 7, string-length($t) - 6))]]/Value/text())[1] cast as xs:string?,
          "|"
         )
')
FROM MyObjects mo;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6384cf448ad267c9d26436bc79daffce)

The assumption here is that you want to join `Object1` to `Value` and `Object2` to `Value2` etc.

Steps are as follows:

- `for $e in List/e` take each `e` node in the `List` root node.
- Assign a variable `$t` containing the text of the first `Type` child node of `$e`.
- Filter where that variable begins with `"Object"`.
- Return a sequence of:

  - The text of the `Name` child node of `$e`
  - A comma `,`
  - The first `e` node where the `Type` child node is `ValueX` where `X` is the remaining part of `$t`. You could also use `contains` instead of `sub-string` and `concat`.
  - A pipe `|`
- The casts are needed because you cannot have mixed sequences of both nodes and strings.
- `.query` will concatenate all sequences together into one big string.

Answer (score 1):

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Details XML);
INSERT @tbl (Details) VALUES
(N'<List>
    <e>
        <Name>Street bike 1</Name>
        <Type>Object1</Type>
    </e>
    <e>
        <Name>Mountain bike 1</Name>
        <Type>Object2</Type>
    </e>
     <e>
        <Value>350</Value>
        <Type>Value1</Type>
    </e>
    <e>
        <Value>300</Value>
        <Type>Value2</Type>
    </e>
</List>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Object VARCHAR(10) = 'Object'
    , @Value VARCHAR(10) = 'Value';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT e.value('(Name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS ObjectName
        , REPLACE(e.value('(Type/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),@Object,'') AS TypeID
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY Details.nodes('(/List/e[Type[contains(.,sql:variable("@Object"))]])') t(e)
), rs2 AS
(
    SELECT e.value('(Value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [Value]
        , REPLACE(e.value('(Type/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),@Value,'') AS TypeID
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY Details.nodes('(/List/e[Type[contains(.,sql:variable("@Value"))]])') t(e)
)
SELECT rs.TypeID, rs.ObjectName, rs2.[Value] 
FROM rs2 
    INNER JOIN rs ON rs2.TypeID = rs.TypeID;
```

**Output**

| TypeID | ObjectName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Street bike 1 | 350 |
| 2 | Mountain bike 1 | 300 |